# Connected and locally connected sets and property of function

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Assume $X$ is connected and $Y$ is an open subset of $Z$.

Fix $x_0\in X$. Assume $f:X\times Y\rightarrow Z$ is a continuous map ($X\times Y$ with product topology)

If $f(x\times Y)$ and $f(x_0\times Y)$ are open for all $x\in X$, and $f(x \times Y)=\coprod_i C_i$, where $C_i$ is a component of $Z$ then is true that for all $x\in X$, $f(x\times Y)=f(x_0\times Y)$?

ideas:

Since $X$ is connected, we must show that $H= \{ x\in X: f(x\times Y)=f(x_0 \times Y)\}$ is closed and open in $X$. Then, since it is non-empty $(x_0\in H)$, we get result. But I am stuck on this.

Comment: "Assume $f(X,y)$ and  $f(x_0,y)$ for all $y\in Y$ are in the same component." Isn't that always satisfied because $f(x_0,y) \in f(X,y)$ and $X$ is connected?

Comment: @PaulFrost right yes. Connected sets are contained in components. Yes. Edited. Thanks

Comment: $f:(0, 1)^2\to (0, 1)$, $f(x, y) = xy$

Comment: @Jakobian Sorry, $f(x,Y)$ is of form $coprod_iC_i$ where $C_i$ component

Comment: @PaulFrost Also, $f(x,Y)$ is union of components

Comment: Just to clarify notation, is $f(x,Y)=f(\{x\}\times Y)$?

Comment: @MW Yup that's correct I edited to make it clear for readers I also just saw your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the topological assumptions on $Y$ or $Z$ or $f(\{x\}\times Y)$ are needed here.  If $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are topological spaces, with $X$ connected, $f\colon X\times Y\to Z$ is continuous, and for each $x\in X$, $f(\{x\}\times Y)$ is a union of components of $Z$, then $f(\{x_1\}\times Y)= f(\{x_2\}\times Y)$ for all $x_1,x_2\in X$.

##### Proof.

Let $z= f(x_1,y)\in f(\{x_1\}\times Y)$.  Let $C$ be the component of $z$ in $Z$.  Then $C\subseteq f(\{x_1\}\times Y)$.  On the other hand, since $X$ is connected, $X\times\{y\}$ is connected, so $f(X\times \{y\})$ is connected by continuity, and intersects $C$ in $z$.  Therefore $f(X\times\{y\})\subseteq C$, so $f(x_2,y)\in C$.

Since $f(\{x_2\}\times Y)$ is a union of components as well, we have $C\subseteq f(\{x_2\}\times Y)$.  Thus $z\in f(\{x_2\}\times Y)$.  This holds for arbitrary $z\in f(\{x_1\}\times Y)$, so $f(\{x_1\}\times Y)\subseteq f(\{x_2\}\times Y)$, and the reverse inclusion follows by symmetry since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are arbitrary, so $f(\{x_1\}\times Y)=f(\{x_2\}\times Y)$.

Comment: @M W Thank you!!! I would upvote 10 times if I could :=)

Comment: @monoidaltransform you're very welcome, glad to help.